# how solver java.lang.StackOverflowError when I use a regex replace in groovy?

Tags: java, regex, groovy, backreference

I'm trying to use this command in large file but this error appears: `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

This is my code

```
stringx.replaceAll(/(\n.*?;(.*?);.*?;.*?;.*?;.+)(\n.*?;\2;.+)+/, '\ntitle\n$1\n$2\n')
```

Comment: yes works perfect please put this in answers for select the best answers

Comment: very thankyou for help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like another case of [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when each `.*?;` is trying to match as small portion of text until *some* `;`. But since `.` can also match `;` when match of entire regex will rail, regex engine will need to backtrack and try to look for different ways for matching `.*?` subexpressions. So it will try to "stretch out" some of them and/or limit the others to make match possible. Stretching out will allow to include `;` in a match, and since there is *a lot* of possibilities here to check (and fact that regex engine is using some recursion) you end up with `StackOverflowError`.

To prevent `.*?;` from matching farther text after `;` we can limit it to match only non-semicolon characters until first semicolon after it. So we can replace each `.*?;` with `[^;\r\n]*;` (we can also get rid of reluctant quantifier that way).

Comment: HI pshemo sorry for reask but I have a same problem with this again I need to know if is possible increase stack size with this code  export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx16384m"

Comment: hi sorry I change stacksize with this in groovy and works               export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss16m"   very thankyou for all

Comment: @user8862613 It is hard to tell. If that backtracking is still happening then for long enough text you may end up with StackOverflowError eventually, even if you add more memory.

Answer (score 1):

very sorry for put two asnwers but I increase the stacksize for solve this problem in groovy with this command thankyou for all for help me

**export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss16m"**